# How do I create a Textfield for Tag-Like-Text Input in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I'm creating a app where the User can input text (words or short phrases) by pressing several buttons.

The text gets inserted into a UITextField, where the user can input additional text of his own. To simplify interaction with the already inserted text, I'd love to have a behavior that is similar to the way the standard messages-app acts when searching contacts for a new conversation, or how Evernote handles Tags.

That means, after they are inserted, the words or phrases are only selectable as a whole, and pressing the Delete-Button on the keyboard selects the whole "Tag" first and deletes it on the next press.

Is there a way to make the standard UITextField behave like this, or is there an open-source-implementation of a UITextField that does?

Comment: Possibly something like this: github.com/venmo/VENTokenField ?

Comment: @benhameen, Thank you a lot! Thats what I was looking for ;) (I'd upvote you, but I can't as i don't yet have enough reputation :\)

Comment: Sure thing! And no worries, up-voting comments is just aesthetic. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed something similar on my OS X application. There they are using something called `NSTokenField` but unfortunately there is no equivalent on iOS platform. So you are basically stuck with creating your own tokens or use existing third-party libraries. If you need details on how to create custom tokens, let me know.

P.S. creating custom tokens requires overriding `drawRect` method and some usage of Bezier paths.

**Expanded answer:**
I'll show you how to create tokens on `NSTextView` (which contains text, but can also contains `NSTextAttachment`. Also, code works on Cocoa (but with little tweaking the same can be achieved in Cocoa Touch.

1.) Create class which extends `NSTextAttachmentCell`

2.) Override method `-(void)drawWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView`

```
- (void)drawWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView
{
    [self drawWithFrame:cellFrame inView:controlView characterIndex:NSNotFound layoutManager:nil];
}
```

And implementation of `- (void)drawWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView characterIndex:(NSUInteger)charIndex layoutManager:(NSLayoutManager *)layoutManager` is like this:

```
- (void)drawWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView     characterIndex:(NSUInteger)charIndex layoutManager:(NSLayoutManager *)layoutManager
{
   NSColor* bgColor = [NSColor redColor];
   NSColor* borderColor = [NSColor blackColor];
   NSRect frame = cellFrame;
   CGFloat radius = ceilf([self cellSize].height / 2.f);
   NSBezierPath* roundedRectanglePath = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: NSMakeRect(NSMinX(frame) + 0.5, NSMinY(frame) + 3.5, NSWidth(frame) - 1, NSHeight(frame) - 1) xRadius: radius yRadius: radius];
   [bgColor setFill];
   [roundedRectanglePath fill];
   [borderColor setStroke];
   [roundedRectanglePath setLineWidth: 1];
   [roundedRectanglePath stroke];
   CGSize size = [[self stringValue] sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:defaultFont}];
CGRect textFrame = CGRectMake(cellFrame.origin.x + (cellFrame.size.width - size.width)/2,
                              cellFrame.origin.y + 2.f,
                              size.width,
                              size.height);
   [[self stringValue] drawInRect:textFrame withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:defaultFont, NSForegroundColorAttributeName:     [NSColor whiteColor]}];
```

}

All the code should be self explanatory, but if you have any questions, please ask. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out drawRect, this will be useful for a few other things my app does. It's really a shame that there is no system solution, but I think I'm gonna use [VENTokenField](http://github.com/venmo/VENTokenField), as suggested by @benhameen in the comments. Thank you again ;)

Comment: Also, I'd like to upvote this answer, but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: Yes, I would suggest the same. But I couldn't find similar library for OS X, so I had to do it myself :) I will extend the answer, maybe someone will find it useful :)

Answer (score 0):

I needed something more hybrid on OS X that allows a mix of Facebook-like tags as well as normal text. So I've built my own implementation https://github.com/aiman86/ANTaggedTextView, this takes care of the view rendering only, and not auto completion or selections (planning to the implement latter soon):

1. Subclass NSTextView and override drawRect

   ```
   - (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
       [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
       [self.attributedString enumerateAttributesInRange:(NSRange){0, self.string.length} options:NSAttributedStringEnumerationReverse usingBlock:
        ^(NSDictionary *attributes, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {
            if ([attributes objectForKey:@"Tag"] != nil)
            {
                NSDictionary* tagAttributes = [self.attributedString attributesAtIndex:range.location effectiveRange:nil];
                NSSize oneCharSize = [@"a" sizeWithAttributes:tagAttributes];
                NSRange activeRange = [self.layoutManager glyphRangeForCharacterRange:range actualCharacterRange:NULL];
                NSRect tagRect = [self.layoutManager boundingRectForGlyphRange:activeRange inTextContainer:self.textContainer];
                tagRect.origin.x += self.textContainerOrigin.x;
                tagRect.origin.y += self.textContainerOrigin.y;
                tagRect = [self convertRectToLayer:tagRect];
                NSRect tagBorderRect = (NSRect){ (NSPoint){tagRect.origin.x-oneCharSize.width*0.25, tagRect.origin.y+1}, (NSSize){tagRect.size.width+oneCharSize.width*0.5, tagRect.size.height} };

                [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
                NSBezierPath* path = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:tagBorderRect xRadius:3.0f yRadius:3.0f];
                NSColor* fillColor = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:237.0/255.0 green:243.0/255.0 blue:252.0/255.0 alpha:1];
                NSColor* strokeColor = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:163.0/255.0 green:188.0/255.0 blue:234.0/255.0 alpha:1];             
                NSColor* textColor = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:37.0/255.0 green:62.0/255.0 blue:112.0/255.0 alpha:1];

                [path addClip];
                [fillColor setFill];
                [strokeColor setStroke];
                NSRectFillUsingOperation(tagBorderRect, NSCompositeSourceOver);
                NSAffineTransform *transform = [NSAffineTransform transform];
                [transform translateXBy: 0.5 yBy: 0.5];
                [path transformUsingAffineTransform: transform];
                [path stroke];
                [transform translateXBy: -1.5 yBy: -1.5];
                [path transformUsingAffineTransform: transform];
                [path stroke];

                NSMutableDictionary* attrs = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:tagAttributes];
                NSFont* font = [tagAttributes valueForKey:NSFontAttributeName];
                font = [[NSFontManager sharedFontManager] convertFont:font toSize:[font pointSize] - 0.25];
                [attrs addEntriesFromDictionary:@{NSFontAttributeName: font, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: textColor}];
                [[self.attributedString.string substringWithRange:range] drawInRect:tagRect withAttributes:attrs];

                [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];
            }
        }];
   }
   ```

   2. Now you can simply use the attribute "Tag" in an NSAttributedString (with any value) and the text view will render the tagged text with similar look and feel to Facebook-like tags.

My implementation at github also provides NSTextField and NSTextFieldCell implementations if you're interested in using it within table views:

[image]

Hope that helps someone who is in a similar situation, please feel free to comment if you see shortcomings, I'm quite new to Cocoa app development.